# How to test file Upload with Swagger

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, swagger

I have the following API which adds users to a database, users must have a profile picture.

I need to be able to test this VIA swagger, but not sure how to do the file upload part in swagger (if that makes sense)

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Adduser([FromBody]User user)
{
    var telemetry = new TelemetryClient();
    try
    {
        var userStore = CosmosStoreHolder.Instance.CosmosStoreUser;
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        //Then we validate the content type
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data"))
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.CustomerId) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.PartnerId))
        {
            return BadRequest("ClientID or PartnerId must be filled in.");
        }

        var added = await userStore.AddAsync(user);
        added.Entity.ProfilePictureUrl = await BlobStorageHelper.Instance.UploadUserProfileImage(Request, added.Entity.Id);
        var updated = await userStore.UpdateAsync(user);
        return Ok(added);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var dt = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "Error Lulo: ", guid }
        };

        telemetry.TrackException(ex, dt);
        return BadRequest("Error Lulo: " + guid);
    }             
}
```

User

```
public class User : ISharedCosmosEntity
{
    [JsonProperty("Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }

    public string ProfilePictureUrl { get; set; }

    public string Base64Image { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string PartnerName { get; set; }

    public string CustomerId{ get; set; }
    public string PartnerId { get; set; }
    public string RoleId { get; set; }

    [CosmosPartitionKey]
    public string CosmosEntityName { get; set; }
}
```

BlobStorageHelper

```
public async Task<string> UploadUserProfileImage(HttpRequestMessage request, string userid)
{
    //Initalize configuration settings
    var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(AccountName, Key), true);
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer imagesContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(ProfilePicsContainer);
    var provider = new AzureStorageMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(imagesContainer);

    // Validate extension and image size
    foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
    {

        var fileName = file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Trim('\"').Trim();
        if (fileName.EndsWith(".png"))
        {
            var img = Image.FromFile(file.LocalFileName);
            if (img.Width != 200 && img.Height != 200)
            {
                string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                throw new ArgumentException($"Error Lulo. Unsupported extension, only PNG is valid. Or unsuported image dimensions (200px x 200px)");
            }
        }
    }

    await request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);


    // Retrieve the filename of the file you have uploaded
    var filename = provider.FileData.FirstOrDefault()?.LocalFileName;
    //Rename file
    CloudBlockBlob blobCopy = imagesContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(userid + ".png");
    if (!await blobCopy.ExistsAsync())
    {
        CloudBlockBlob blob = imagesContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);

        if (await blob.ExistsAsync())
        {
            await blobCopy.StartCopyAsync(blob);
            await blob.DeleteIfExistsAsync();
        }
    }

    return blobCopy.Name;

}
```

I tried to post only the relevant part

Comment: hello sir, may you want to check this out! https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2019/august/handling-file-uploads-in-swagger-ui-with-aspnet-core/

Comment: its asp.net, not asp.net core

Comment: You have ProfilePictureUrl in the User POCO. Is this the same as "added.Entity.ProfilePictureUrl". If not then why can't you just copy the first to the second? Also you have Base64Image in the User, you can use this to upload the image into your Blob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a custom attribute to accept a file:

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public sealed class SwaggerParameterAttribute : Attribute
{
    public SwaggerParameterAttribute(string name, string description)
    {
        Name = name;
        Description = description;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public string Description { get; private set; }

    public string Type { get; set; } = "text";

    public bool Required { get; set; } = false;
}
```

2. Add a filter to handle the new attribute:

```cs
public class SwaggerParameterOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
    {
        var requestAttributes = apiDescription.GetControllerAndActionAttributes<SwaggerParameterAttribute>();
        if (requestAttributes.Any())
        {
            operation.parameters = operation.parameters ?? new List<Parameter>();

            foreach (var attr in requestAttributes)
            {
                operation.parameters.Add(new Parameter
                {
                    name = attr.Name,
                    description = attr.Description,
                    @in = attr.Type == "file" ? "formData" : "body",
                    required = attr.Required,
                    type = attr.Type
                });
            }

            if (requestAttributes.Any(x => x.Type == "file"))
            {
                operation.consumes.Add("multipart/form-data");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3. Update your Swagger configuration to use the filter:

```cs
config.EnableSwagger(c =>
{
    c.OperationFilter<SwaggerParameterOperationFilter>();
    // ....
}
```

4. Add the attribute to your controller endpoint:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[SwaggerParameter("profilePicture", "A file", Required = true, Type = "file")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Adduser([FromBody]User user)
{
//...
}
```

---

Adapted from the following [blogpost](https://tahirhassan.blogspot.com/2017/12/web-apiswagger-file-upload.html).

Answer (score 2):

I know it's not swagger but you can use Postman instead.
While using Postman. 
You can simulate a http call to your application and passing it the data of your form.

You can choose the type of data, and if you choose form-data, you have either choice between text or file.

File let's you upload a file and pass it to your api. So maybe you'll find everything you need to test it.

[image: Postman choose file parameter]