# NET 6 Web Api: File Uploading does not work

Tags: asp.net-core

I develop NET 6 Web API service.
One of methods (I have minimized the code):

```
[HttpPost("upload201")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload201FileAsync(IFormFile file, string bucketName, string? prefix)
{
    return Ok($"File {prefix}/{file.FileName} uploaded to S3 successfully!");
}
```

But when I test it in Swagger the app crashes immediately when I opent file in Swagger.
If I run it in VS2022 the app stops disappeared without any messages.
In both cases I even cannot reach a debug point in the method.
What is the reason?

Comment: What is your client-side code? I wonder if Swagger supports testing endPoints with file upload.

Comment: My client now is Swagger. The future client app will be developed later. I do server part only.

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58874379/how-to-test-file-upload-with-swagger

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test file Upload with Swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58874379/how-to-test-file-upload-with-swagger)

Comment: It seems interesting, I will try it. Add this as your answer.

Comment: Check. I voted to close this issue as it has a clear answer in the link provided ;)

Comment: Your project crashes immediately without any error message? Have you try to use Postman to send request to your Api? I am not sure if this issue caused by swagger or your web api

Comment: Yes, 2 ways: I run 1. VS2022->Debug - the app disappeared immediately but VS2022 stays .  2. I go to build folder, run exe and the same: the app disappears. In both cases no any exceptions, info etc. A thriller ;-)

Comment: Have you set the endpoint here to check if this endpoint can receive `IFormFile` file successfully?

Comment: How can I do it?